# Using a field variable to get an order BY Query? C#

Tags: c#, variables

I was wondering how i can setup my program to order by different names, for example i have Firstname,lastname and so forth so i want to store it in a setter/getter but my ways of doing it isn't working/isn't correct. Can someone please point my into the right direction?

the code i have right now is this:

```
    private string sortbyprev;

    private string SortByPrev
    {
        get
        {
            return sortbyprev;
        }

        set
        {
            if (cbSort.SelectedItem.ToString() == "First Name")
            {
                sortbyprev = DataStrings.CLIENTS_FIRSTNAME;
            }
        }
    }
```

And this:

```
        public void next()
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection(DataStrings.CONNECTION_STRING);//Gets Connection
            dbConn.Open(); // Opens connection
            string query = "SELECT * FROM tblClients WHERE ClientsID > " + activeID + " ORDER BY "+ SortByPrev + " ASC"; //Query
            OleDbCommand dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(query, dbConn);  //gets query and DB Conn for command execution
            var reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();// Executes oledbcommand
            reader.Read(); //Advances to next record
            txtFirstName.Text = reader["firstName"].ToString();
            txtLastName.Text = reader["lastName"].ToString();
            dtpDOB.Text = reader["clientDOB"].ToString();
            txtDesc.Text = reader["Description"].ToString();

            activeID = (int)reader["ClientsID"];

            dbConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why isn't it working?

Comment: Your `SortByPrev.set` is very strange. How do you use it? You know that this code is called when you call `SortByPrev = "somestring"` and `"somestring"` is passed to that method as argument `value`? Did you set it somewhere?

Comment: I'm trying to set lets say firstName to the query string so for example.. SELECT * FROM tblClients WHERE ClientsID > " + activeID + " ORDER BY firstName DESC

Answer (score 0):

If do not pay attention to quality of your code (there are many  remarks about it) then i think that [Dynamic LINQ library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) is what you need.